# Undefined method when using rspec and macros

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Here's my request spec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Password pages" do
  describe "user views his passwords" do
    let(:user) { create(:user) }

    sign_in(:user)

  end
end
```

**spec_helper.rb**

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods

  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

  config.order = "random"

  config.include Capybara::DSL

  config.include LoginMacros
end
```

**support/login_macros.rb**

```
module LoginMacros
  def sign_in(user)
    visit new_user_session_path

    fill_in 'Email', with: user.email
    fill_in 'Password', with: user.password
    click_button 'Sign in'
  end
end
```

When running spec I get error:

```
/spec/requests/account_pages_spec.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>': undefined method `sign_in' for #<Class:0x007fd4f97183f8> (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: Try putting sign_in call in a before block.

Answer (score 0):

I use this cool technics but another way:

Create page class:

```
class PageObject
  include Capybara::DSL

  def visit_page(page)
    visit(page)
    self
  end

  def login(user)    
    fill_in 'Email', with: user.email
    fill_in 'Password', with: user.password
    click_button 'Sign in'
  end
end
```

create `feature` instead `describe`:

```
require 'spec_helper'

feature 'test authozire page' do
  let(:login_page) { PageObject.new }
  let(:user) { create(:user) }

  scenario 'login page have field' do
    page = login_page.visit_page(new_user_session_path)
    expect(page.have_field?('email')).to be_true
    expect(page.have_field?('password')).to be_true
  end

  scenario "user can login" do
    login_page.visit_page(new_user_session_path).login(user)
    # more awesome test
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, but I still get the same error.